# Selecting all data from a MySQL database table based on a DateTimePicker value

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'd like to select all data from a table where the DATE will be coming from a `DateTimePicker`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM income_table WHERE income_date='" + 
                   dateShower.Value + "';";
cmd.Connection = connection;
MySqlDataReader myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    txtIncomeList.Text = Convert.ToString(myDataReader["income_subcategory"] + 
                           "\t\t" + myDataReader["income_amount"] + "\r\n" +
                           myDataReader["income_vendor"]+ "\t\t" + 
                           myDataReader["income_paidby"]+"\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you not getting any results? Your `dateShower.Value` is likely not matching your database values exactly and thus not returning anything.

Comment: it doesn't retrieve any data from the table I don't think that dateShower.Value is not in the same format with mySql @_@

Comment: Ok, guys, why did we delete the c# tag? This is c# code.

Comment: If this is a web app you should use parameterised queries, otherwise it's a SQL injection attack just waiting to happen.

Comment: @gunr2171 because the problem isn't with the c# code. The question is related to a sql query

Comment: @ethorn10 - the problem lies within both the OP's understanding of C# and MySQL, more C# to be honest.

Comment: Fair enough. I see it as more of a misunderstanding of how date comparisons work at the database, but I'll play along.

Comment: :) so since we're now all on the same track... does any one have an idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What date time picker are you using?

Comment: ahm...? what do you mean by what date time picker am I using? :) it's a datetimepicker from visual studio 2010 under windows application ahm its in a "FORMAT: LONG" does this answer the question? :D

Comment: Do you mean "FORMAT: LONG" is the data type of the `income_date` column in your MySQL database?

Comment: Format long is what the datetimepicker says in the properties... in the database the income_date is DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in the sql query where you are matching datetimepicker value (date and time) with "income_date" field data which is not possible to retrieve any data, you have to edit your query to compare date between 2 ranges like below :

```
"SELECT * FROM income_table WHERE income_date > = '" + dateShower.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + " 00:00:00" + "' and income_date <= '" + dateShower.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + " 23:59:59" + "'";
```